# .Net Maui Blazor - Bring next application to foreground on Android

Tags: android, .net, maui-blazor, maui-android

I have a .Net Maui Blazor application and when a button is clicked on Android, the next application should be brought to the foreground, like the Alt-Tab action in Windows. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the Alt-Tab action in Windows` is a windows platforms shortcut, but the android system doesn't provide a such shortcut or feature.

But the android provides [Recents screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents), and if you want to bring next application to foreground on Android. You can refer to my old answer about [Getting the list of running processes in Android OS using Net Maui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75358791/17455524) to get `the next application`. And then you can launch the app programmatically by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72105751/17455524).

**Note:** The `android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS` permission is a [signature-level permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37535896/17455524).